# rails to_xml/to_json options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am currently playing with rails, and I am trying to render my models to xml and json.

Now, in all my models I want to remove the created_at and updated_at columns - and adding an except to every single one of my to_xml/json is against DRY.

so I am wondering how can I do that.

I saw people overriding to_xml method - but i still have to do that to every model - and what if there is this one place i will need those columns?

I am looking for something like

```
xxx = :except => [:created_at, :updated_at]
```

and in each rendering I send xxx to the options.

- For the record - I know how to use to_json/to_xml - i just don't want to repeat these frequently used options.

Comment: it gave me a lead - my answer is what i finally did

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up creating a module overriding serializable_hash (for json and xml)

```
module DefaultRenderingModule

  def serializable_hash (options = {})
    if(options.has_key? :all)
       super(options.except!(:all))
    else
      x = [:created_at, :updated_at]
      if options.has_key? :except
        x.append(options[:except])
      end
      options.merge! :except => x
      super(options)
    end
  end
end
```

and I include it in every model i want this behavior

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
xxx.to_json(:except => [ :created_at, :updated_at ])
```

Comment: are you mocking me? or does that actually solve my problem? - you are just placing the :except option. I know how to do that, i just don't want to do it in every render...

Comment: Sorry you felt being mocked at.... and this was misleading ( but i still have to do that to every model - and what if there is this one place i will need those columns?)

Comment: Well instead of directly using options, create a helper method, and send the active_record object to it. place the to_json with the options you require there. it wall start returning what you want..

Comment: that actually brilliant, why didn't i think of that... Maybe I just thought that there was a built in rails way to do that

Answer (score 0):

Check docs http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Serialization/to_json:

```
xxx.to_json(:except => [ :id, :created_at, :age ])
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers for me that's the way

Answer (score 0):

Override as_json in your model.  This is what is used to generate the json when you do a

render :json => @object

```
def as_json(options = {})
  super(options.merge(:except => [:created_at, :updated_at]))
end
```

You can play around with this - use the options submitted or not.

Use :only, :methods, and :include to completely customize the output.